# Get list of named queries in NHibernate

Tags: unit-testing, nhibernate, named-query

I have a dozen or so named queries in my NHibernate project and I want to execute them against a test database in unit tests to make sure the syntax still matches the changing domain/database model.  Currently I have a unit test for each named query where I get and execute the query, for example:

```
IQuery query = session.GetNamedQuery("GetPersonSummaries");
var personSummaryArray = query.List();
Assert.That(personSummaryArray, Is.Not.Null);
```

This works fine, but I would like to have one unit test that loops thru all of the named queries and executes them.  Is there a way to discover all of the available named queries?

Thanks
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Configuration.NamedQueries` has a list of named queries (it's an IDictionary, the key is the query name)

Of course, you'll need access to the `Configuration` instance, or save that list somewhere.

Comment: FYI, there is also a NamedSqlQueries property to the Configuration object (which is what I actually needed).